# On Call returns Null Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

Simple OnCall Return Null And im unable to pinpoint the issue.

Call function->

```
const schedule = () => {
    const functions = getFunctions(getApp());
    const scheduleAppointment = httpsCallable(functions, "scheduleOperation");
    scheduleAppointment({ text: "messageText" })
      .then((result) => {
        console.log(result.data);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
      });
  };
```

All my Functions are stored in different folders for example "scheduleOperation" stored in "./appointment" and I just import them from their folder to the main functions Index.js  on my Functions folder.

Before I Start to fill my functions I just want it to return simple response

Firebase Function->

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
const url = require("url");
const cors = require("cors")({ origin: true });
var serviceAccount = require("../serviceAccountKey.json");

exports.scheduleOperation = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
  return{
    data: {
      firstNumber: "First",
    };
});
```

```
//----------------------//

The Index function which calls Schedule operation->
//----------------------//
const { scheduleOperation } = require("./appointment");
const client = new Client({});
exports.scheduleOperation = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
  scheduleOperation(data, context, client);
});
```

Expected:

```
{
    data: {
      firstNumber: "First",
    };
}
```

Received :

```
Null
```

Any Ideas? this is only with onCall function OnRequests works fine

Firebase dependencies: "firebase": "9.17.1",

Comment: I don't understand what your function code is supposed to do.  It appears to be exporting two functions with the same name.  If your intent is to have a callable invoke another callable, that's definitely not going to work.  The second function doesn't need to be "oncall" at all.  It can just be a regular javascript function.

Comment: Hello Doug Thank you for answering me! 

Apologies for being unclear, I will try to explain:

All my Functions are stored in different folders for example "scheduleOperation" stored in "./appointment" and I just import them from their folder to the main functions Index.js  on my Functions folder

I have edited the post so Maybe it will be more clear

Comment: You still can't have one callable invoke another like that.  It just doesn't work, and it's not clear why you've set it up like this.

Comment: Thank you Doug, You helped me to resolve this, It was indeed the issue, I just didn't want all my functions  to be crumped on Index.js so I Imported the OnCall Function from another folder, I Just Posted the resolution

Answer (score 0):

So The answer is, You cannot OnCall and Invoke another On Call, I tried to do it so my Code will look more nicer and not crump all my functions in on Index.

A workaround was to write the OnCall Function in Another folder and import it like so ->

OnCal Func is located in another folder->

```
exports.scheduleOperation = functions.https.onCall((request, response) => {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    resolve({ data: { firstNumber: "First" } });
  });
});
```

Then Import it Directly from Index using Require->

```
const scheduleOperation = require("./appointment").scheduleOperation;
```

Lastly, Export it From Index directly ->

```
exports.scheduleOperation = scheduleOperation;
```

Hopefully This will help another newbie like me

Comment: For added context, `onCall` adds special logic around the handler function you provide so that it can handle the raw HTTP request it receives from the client apps. While you can't invoke a `onCall` function from another `onCall`, you can invoke its handler instead if you export it. e.g. `exports.scheduleOperationHandler = (data, context) => { /* ... */ }` and then use it like `functions.https.onCall(scheduleOperationHandler)` in your `index.js` file.

Comment: Thank you for The input Sam! I will implement it right away, Btw theres no need to export functions.https.onCall(scheduleOperationHandler) ?

Comment: You will need to still export the function for it to work. I omitted it in my comment for space.